# Solve $\sinh z = i$

Tags: complex-numbers

I am trying to solve $\sinh z = i$; this has to result in $2\pi n + (1/2) \pi i$. When applying the exponential form of $$\sinh z = \frac{e ^ z - e ^ {-z}} 2$$ and later the quadratic equation, this does not give me the result as described above. I would appreciate your collaboration guiding me to find the error.

Comment: What is "senh"? Do you mean $\sinh$ or maybe the hyperbolic secant?

Comment: sin h (sin hhyperbolic )

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Please show your work

Comment: Ok, this is my work : sinh(z) = i    ---- >  (e^z - e ^ -z) / 2 =  i  -----> (e^z - e ^ -z)  = 2i ---- > e^2z -  1 = 2i e^z   ----- >  (e^z)^2 - 2i e^z -1 = 0   ----- > aplly the quadratic equation  ----- > -(-2) +- √ (-2)^2 -4(1)(-1) / 2(-1)   -----> solve this 2+- 2i  . At this point I find the fault, because when applying the function Ln | r | + i (Ø + 2π), the result is not the same as that indicated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You have\begin{align}\sinh z=i&\iff e^z-e^{-z}=2i\\&\iff(e^z)^2-2ie^z-1=0\\&\iff(e^z-i)^2=0\\&\iff e^z=i\\&\iff z=\frac\pi2i+2k\pi i\end{align}for some $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for answering, I have a question about the given explanation, because ⟺ (ez)^2-2ie^z-1 = 0 is the same e^z = i?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Is it clear now?